Convergence in $L^\infty$($\Omega$) and almost everywhere
I have a question about the difference between the convergence in $L^\infty$ and convergence almost everywhere.
Precisly, let $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$, $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1(\Omega)$, then there exists a subsequence {$f_{n_j}$} $\subset$ ${f_n}$ such that $f_{n j}\rightarrow f$ almost everywhere.
Can we conclude that $||f_{n j}-f||_\infty$ $\rightarrow 0$ ?

Consider $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, and let $f_n = n \cdot\textbf{1}_{[0,1/n^2])}$, where $\textbf{1}_A$ is the indicator function of $A$. Then $f_n \rightarrow 0$ a.e. and in $L^1([0,1])$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but $\|f_n\|_\infty = n \rightarrow \infty$.
